# Use of Inverse Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I solved a matrix as follows:

```
{{0,1,1},{0,2,4},{0,3,9}}.{{0},{25},{20}}
```

Resulting:

```
{{45},{130},{255}}
```

I tried to use an inverse matrix to solve:

```
Inverse[{{0,1,1},{0,2,4},{0,3,9}}].{{45},{130},{255}}
```

Wishing the following solution:

```
{{0},{25},{20}}
```

But this matrix is singular:

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [PseudoInverse](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PseudoInverse.html):

```
mat = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 9}}; 
PseudoInverse[mat].{{45}, {130}, {255}}
```

> {{0}, {25}, {20}}

or, [LeastSquares](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeastSquares.html) (thanks: J.M.)

```
LeastSquares[mat, {{45}, {130}, {255}}]
```

> {{0}, {25}, {20}}

Comment: ...but using `LeastSquares[]` is better.

Comment: @J.M., thank you. Updated with that alternative.

Comment: @J.M.: I don't disagree that it is an alternate approach, but why is it better? Speed, numerical accuracy, ...?

Comment: @Moo, it's a more expensive and potentially less stable way to get the same result; for `LeastSquares[]` (and `LinearSolve[]`, for that matter), one generates an appropriate matrix decomposition which is then easily applied to the right-hand side. For `PseudoInverse[]` (and `Inverse[]`, for that matter), one has to generate the required matrix from the previously mentioned decompositions, which is already expensive in itself; the additional dot product is yet another opportunity for instability to show up.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

[`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) will also solve underdetermined systems.

```
LinearSolve[{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 9}}, {{45}, {130}, {255}}]
(*  {{0}, {25}, {20}}  *)
```

One can use `Solve` as well, although the solution has a different form:

```
Solve[{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 9}}.{x, y, z} == {{45}, {130}, {255}},
 {x, y, z}]
(*  {{y -> 25, z -> 20}}  *)
```

Here `x` is a free variable, which can be assigned any real number.